# Getting error Installation failed after generating Signed APK

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, apk

I Generated signed APK because I wanted to release my app but after generating signed APK, the app wont run on the emulator."app-release.apk is not signed. Please configure the signing information for the selected flavor using the project structure dialog."

To resolve this error, I did what it told me to do. I went to project structure>signing and added signing info (called config). Then i added this config info to build Types and Flavors. Gradle synced successfully and I was able to run my app in emulator.However, when emulator starts, I see a dialog box in my android studio saying *************"Installation failed because device already has an application with the same package but a different signature".******************[image] Also, I noticed that any changes that I did to my app after running the "Generate Signed APK" wizard are not reflected in the app. I cleaned the project and restarted android studio but same results.

**I am attaching a screenshot of the error that i am getting

Comment: Error says clearly..device has one more app with same package..remove it and install again

Comment: in your manifest, change package name

Answer (score 1):

what you have is you have different builds for production and debug i guess or more if you want to install you production apk you have to uninstall the app from your emulator as one device can't install the two apps with same package names,uninstall the apk installed in the emulator and then generate a signed apk with whatever configuration you are generating then this apk will be installed in your emulator

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I uninstalled the application but didnt lose any project activity as I had imagined. All is working fine for now. Any edits are reflected in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed the app previous to the export. Exporting your apk signs it differently than the debug build. Do what the error says and uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: will I lose any data when I uninstall? I wanted to release the app and thats why I generated Signed APK but turns out, I need to work some more on this. So If I reinstall at this point, no harm to project?

Comment: @shrbisht, You will lose all private data associated with the app uppon uninstall. ie any data stored in /data. There is no way around this to my knowledge.

Comment: I want to add that I have a dev phone and have tried copying files from /data/data, reinstalling and copying back; to no avail. I think (don't know, though) that private data is salted with your apk key, meaning it needs to be manually recreated if your key changes (like changing from a "debug" build to an "export" build).